# How to get first element of split Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

Within Google Sheets, the function
`=SPLIT(IMPORTXML("url here", "//title"),"|")`
returns the following:

`{"Linear Algebra", "School of Mathematics", "College Name", "City Name"}`
which takes up 4 cells horizontally.

How do I get the first element of this array, `"Linear Algebra"`?

I don't want to use `FIND()` and `LEFT()`, because as far as I can tell it will take XML lookups.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered my own question with a little more googling:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307788/get-first-item-from-split

`=INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML("url here", "//title"),"|"),1,1)` works.